# Where to place miscellaneous widely used functions?

Tags: swift

this questions follows on from [Is there a neat way to represent a fraction as an attributed string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883994/is-there-a-neat-way-to-represent-a-fraction-as-an-attributed-string).

i have a function that provides a font for a fraction string

```
func fractionFont() -> UIFont {
    let pointSize = CGFloat(20.0)
    let systemFontDescriptor = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(pointSize, weight: UIFontWeightLight).fontDescriptor()
    let fractionFontDescriptor = systemFontDescriptor.fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes(
    [
        UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: [
        [
            UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kFractionsType,
            UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kDiagonalFractionsSelector,
        ], ]
    ] )
    return UIFont(descriptor: fractionFontDescriptor, size: pointSize)
}
```

and i use in it for a label property in `SomeClass`

```
class SomeClass {
    @IBOutlet weak var fractionLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            fractionLabel.text = "1/2"
            fractionLabel.font = fractionFont()
        }
    }
}
```

say i want to use `fractionFont` method again in `AnotherClass` i guess copying the code is not a great idea. i was also advised in another post to use so called `Singleton` classes sparingly, so what's the best approach for this?

- thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd extend `UIFont` with your `fractionFont` method:

```
extension UIFont {
    class func fractionFont() -> UIFont {
        /* Code here */
    }
}
```

Comment: Best part about this is that Swift will let you reference the class method without the class name if the type is inferred. `fractionLabel.font = .fractionFont()`

Comment: @mipadi great - whats the practice for adding these extensions - in a dedicated .swift file?

Comment: @Alex: If there's another file it makes sense it (maybe something dealing with fonts or other UI details) I'd put it there. Otherwise, a separate file would be fine.

Comment: @mipadi thanks - made an "Extensions.swift" and it worked a treat following advice from NateCook.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like `Misc`
Paste your function as class func in there.
Now you can call it like this `fractionLabel.font = Misc.fractionFont()`